# Gem Problems with running Warbler under Maven

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, jruby, bundler, maven-3

I am seeing something odd with our build management server (we are using Jenkins CI). Projects are built using Maven (version 3.0.3)

Other environment details:
`Rails 3.1.3`
`Jruby 1.6.7`
`Ruby 1.9.2`
`Bundler 1.0.22 for rails gem management`
`warbler 1.3.5`

We have a bash script which runs a bundle install, assets:precompile (rake task) and the rake war task:

```
jruby -S bundle install
jruby -S bundle exec rake assets:precompile
jruby -S bundle exec rake war RAILS_ENV=production
```

The `pom.xml` file for the project has a task called `package` which basically runs the above bash script, among some other post-build cleanup stuff.

**My question:**

If I run `mvn package` I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ..... Previous output of maven stuff .....
[INFO] + jruby -S bundle exec rake war RAILS_ENV=production
[INFO] Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
[INFO]       materialize at /mnt/data_drive/opt/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88
[INFO]              map! at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2371
[INFO]       materialize at /mnt/data_drive/opt/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82
[INFO]             specs at /mnt/data_drive/opt/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:107
[INFO]         specs_for at /mnt/data_drive/opt/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:152
[INFO]   requested_specs at /mnt/data_drive/opt/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:141
[INFO]   requested_specs at /mnt/data_drive/opt/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23
[INFO]             setup at /mnt/data_drive/opt/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11
[INFO]             setup at /mnt/data_drive/opt/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:110
[INFO]            (root) at /mnt/data_drive/opt/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17
```

**However** if I simply run, in the command line in the project folder:

```
jruby -S bundle exec rake war RAILS_ENV=production
```

(which is essentially the command it seems to be barfing on) - everything succeeds, and it builds the WAR no problems, finds all the gem files, etc.

I am wondering if anyone would have any suggestions as to what the problem might be. I have done a `jruby -S gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'` and also, just in case, a `gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'` - however it has made no difference.

Any advice is appreciated :)  Thanks!